# Powershell commandlet Add-AzureRmServiceFabricClusterCertificate fails to add secondary certificate to Azure Service Fabric Cluster

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-powershell, x509certificate2

Add-AzureRmServiceFabricClusterCertificate 
`-ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName`
-Name $sfClusterName `
-SecretIdentifier "https://$keyVaultName.vault.azure.net/secrets/SecretCerticate/$newCertificateSecretVersion"

I am using PowerShell 5 with Module AzureRm, the above commandlet fails with the below message. The Service Fabric Cluster already have a Certificate with 3 x Nodes.

> Message        : Code:ClusterUpgradeFailed, Message:Cluster upgrade
>   failed. Reason Code: 'UpgradeServiceDown', Upgrade Progress: ''.
>   ,Details:
>
> Data           : {} InnerException : TargetSite     : StackTrace     :
>   HelpLink       : Source         : HResult        : -2146233088

Also the commandlet runs for longer than 2 hours and then fails.